# Purpose of Using Passing in Argument as *fruit_bowl in Pytest Documentation

Tags: python, pytest

I am looking through the pytest documentation, and there is a small detail that is driving me crazy.

I'm currently looking at the documentation for this page, and it gives the following example:

```
import pytest


class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cubed = False

    def cube(self):
        self.cubed = True


class FruitSalad:
    def __init__(self, *fruit_bowl):
        self.fruit = fruit_bowl
        self._cube_fruit()

    def _cube_fruit(self):
        for fruit in self.fruit:
            fruit.cube()


# Arrange
@pytest.fixture
def fruit_bowl():
    return [Fruit("apple"), Fruit("banana")]


def test_fruit_salad(fruit_bowl):
    # Act
    fruit_salad = FruitSalad(*fruit_bowl)

    # Assert
    assert all(fruit.cubed for fruit in fruit_salad.fruit)
```

I get the basic idea of what is happening on this page, but the inclusion of the `*` in the `fruit_bowl` argument is confusing to me.

For example, if you just want to initialize the classes by themselves the code would not work:

```
fruit_bowl = [Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Banana")]
fruit_salad = FruitSalad(fruit_bowl)
```

returns the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cube'
```

In this case replace the `*fruit_bowl` argument with just `fruit_bowl` works fine.

Then I realized that `fruit_bowl` was defined as a function, so I thought that would do the trick, but again just running the code outside of a test returned an error.

If I setup the code like this:

```
def fruit_bowl():
    return [Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Banana")]

class Fruit():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cubed = False
        
    def cube(self):
        self.cubed = True

class FruitSalad():
    
    def __init__(self, *fruit_bowl):
        self.fruit_bowl = fruit_bowl
        self._cube_fruit()
        
    def _cube_fruit(self):
        for fruit in self.fruit_bowl:
            fruit.cube()
```

Then running `fruit_salad = FruitSalad(fruit_bowl)` gives the error message `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cube'`.

Does this mean the use of the `*fruit_bowl` argument is specific to how pytest works?  Ie, these things will only work if the argument is a function with the `@fixture` decorator added, or is there some other point I'm missing.

At the moment I find the listed code confusing because the non pytest code does not work as-is, so I struggle to see how I'd implement the use of fixtures with my own work.

Comment: `fruit_bowl` the function is shadowed by `fruit_bowl` the argument. And `*` is known as "sequence unpacking". It turns a sequence that would be passed as a single argument into each of its elements being passed as a different argument.

Answer (score 1):

No, the * argument unpacking isn't integral to Pytest at all. I'd call the argument to FruitSalad `fruits`, get rid of the *s. (on both declaration and invocation) and annotate it with `List[Fruit]` to make it crystal clear.